A Title "That in Aleppo Was"
I remember a title, not a book or a story, but a title of some piece of literature I read or heard about decades ago.  The title was something like "That in Aleppo Was".
And so I am asking if there is any real work of literature titled something like That (or What?) in Aleppo Was (or Is?), or if my subconscious mind made it up.

There is a 1969 book In Aleppo Once by Taqui Altounyan that I hope to read some day (https://www.the-independent.com/news/obituaries/taqui-altounyan-9137712.html ).

Possibly, you are vaguely remembering the short story "That in Aleppo Once …", which Vladimir Nabokov published in The Atlantic in November 1943.
The words of the title are taken from Othello's last speech before he kills himself (Othello, 5.2):

(…) Set you down this.
And say besides, that in Aleppo once,
Where a malignant and a turbanned Turk
Beat a Venetian and traduced the state,
I took by th’ throat the circumcisèd dog,
And smote him, thus.
[He stabs himself.]

